# Footer does not render correctly (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, layout, view

I have defined **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
...
<body>

    @RenderBody()

    @if (IsSectionDefined("_Footer"))
    {
        @RenderSection("_Footer")
    }
    else
    {
        <footer>Copyright @DateTime.Now.Year</footer>
    }

</body>
...
```

I have created **_Footer.cshtml** inside folder: *Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml*.

No I want to add it to my view:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

//html code
```

**RenderBody** has been generated but I always get **footer** from **else - Copyright 2019**.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A section isn't an other file, that would be a partial view. A section is a container inside the view.

Inside your view, if you add this (with data inside) then it should replace your default.

```
@section _Footer {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give @Html.Partial("Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml") in _Layout.cshtml. so that it will render in every page.

```
@RenderBody()
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml")
```